# Kentico Admin - Re-arrange Order of checkboxes

Tags: kentico

For my Articles page type, I have an Author field that displays a list of Employees as checkboxes in alpha order based on their names. The thing is for articles, the authors are listed based on their contribution level (not their names).

Example: in admin - the checkboxes are listed in alpha like this: Bill | Fill | Jill | Will.

On the article webpage - the author can be in any order such as: Will, Jill, Bill

How should I go about doing that? 
I was thinking about creating multiple Author fields (Author1, Author2, Author3 etc), but that's cumbersome.

Is there a way to make the checkboxes draggable so that we can move checkboxes arround & re-arrange for each individual article, if needed. If that can't be done, what's your suggestion to go about doing this. Thanks for your input!

**Added Screenshots:**

[image: Author field]
[image: Articles]

Comment: I am not sure I understand you- only to clarify - can you attach screenshot of your authors field in the page type application? Where do you want dragable checkboxes? On the live site you can order items by order by properties in your listing webpart (or ciontrol).

Comment: Screenshot adde

Comment: Why you need it dragable in Page types application? Where should it be reflected? AFAIK it`s not possible without further customizations (if any) but if you want to order it in different way, you can still do it in your datasource query for this field (ORDER BY clause).

Comment: Draggable is just my idea of solving the problem, but any other solutions would do. The real problem to solve is: the list of authors displayed in admin is pre-defined by the SQL query based job ranking & name (CEO, CFO are the first) but for EACH article, CEO, CFO may not be the first one to be listed because he's not the main writer, in some articles he can be the last one, in other he can be the first one or the middle one.Hope it's clear.

Comment: I found this one [Multiple Choice Dual List](https://devnet.kentico.com/marketplace/inline-controls/dual-list-multi-select-form-(with-sort)), but not sure how to use it. Could you advise?

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest to convert your authors into pages (e.g. content only) and then use **Pages** field on your Article page type that allows you to order your authors (using arrows).

Comment: I've just added screenshots. I guess, it should be clearer. My authors are indeed in separate pages.

Comment: Regrettably, there is no dragable checkbox list form control by default (you can implement one though) but with Pages form control there are arrows to order (prioritize) your authors:
https://s17.postimg.org/juct1njwf/2016_12_01_09_20_37.png

Comment: The reason I can't do what you suggested because my authors (most of them are leaders) are also displayed on other pages such as the leadership page or in different contact boxes. Re-arrange authors each time when adding new article will also make the order of leaders/contacts (sorted by NodeOrder) changed and not correct.

Comment: I found this one [Multiple Choice Dual List](https://devnet.kentico.com/marketplace/inline-controls/dual-list-multi-select-form-(with-sort)), but not sure how to use it. Could you advise?

Comment: This could actually solve your issue. It's a form control you simply import to Kentio amd you're good to go!