# Kentico Admin - Dynamically Change and SAVE Field Name, Value and Label

Tags: kentico

For a custom page type, I have a multiple choice form filed as seen in image 1 and 2. I was able to set it up (using jquery) so that when I click on other checkboxes belonging to a another field, the checkbox Label and value of this field is changed accordingly as seen in image 3 - 'Author1', 'Author2', 'Author3' were replaced with something else.

The problem is when I hit the Save button, all of my new label/value are not Saved, but the checkbox value and label return to its original value.

**Is there a way to make it so that these checkboxes can accept new value and the new value can be saved. Thanks!**

[image: Form field]
[image: Form field displayed on admin]
[image: Form field label and value change but can't be saved]

Answer (score 1):

Where does authors values come from? Database? You should be able to use SQL query as data source for multiple choice control. This will allow you to store actual values into database whenever you save a page on the Form tab.

So the idea is to load actual values, replace them with 'AuthorN' and change back to original value when checked.

Comment: Oh I didn't want to refer to [another question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40895771/kentico-admin-re-arrange-order-of-checkboxes) I have in the forum but both questions are related. Basically, my real list of authors come from SQL query, but the order of authors listed is not the order I want for each article.  That's why I'm thinking about adding another field with 5 placeholder checkboxes, then dynamically change the values of these placeholder checkboxes to have the name in the order I want.

Comment: Can't you order them with SQL?

Comment: I don't think so, since it's pretty random - it's based on the amount of contribution: the one who contributed the most will get listed first. It's not big deal to me (as developer) but it's a sensitive thing and big deal to others, especially the authors themselves.

Comment: But you've already implemented some logic on client side to order them, correct? So you could reuse it to re-order checkboxes

Comment: Not really because there's no real programming rule to order them. Real headache

Answer (score 0):

I've set up an example which might help you. I've created a form with three fields:

**FirstAuthor**

- Type: Integer
- Form control: Radio buttons
- Data source: SQL Query (`select userid,username from cms_user`)
- Has depending fields: true

**SecondAuthor**

- Type: Integer
- Form control: Radio buttons
- Data source: SQL Query (`select userid,username from cms_user`)
- Has depending fields: true

**OrderedAuthors**

- Type: Text (1000)
- Form control: Label
- Default value: `{% (if(firstauthor>0) { GlobalObjects.Users.Where("userid="+firstauthor)[0].UserName  } else {""}) + ", " + (if(secondauthor>0) {GlobalObjects.Users.Where("userid="+secondauthor)[0].UserName} else {""} #%}`
- Depends on another field: true

I guess you have a list of authors somewhere in the database so you can just replace CMS_User table with your table. Then all you need to do is to adjust the macro in the third field to give you results you want.